# NSRangeException index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0] for non-empty array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsrangeexception

**Context:** I'm currently on Assignment 2 for Stanford's most recent cs193p course on iTunes U. I'm trying to avoid simply looking up the solutions, but I'm stuck.

**Problem:** For the following code:

```
for (Card *c in self.chosenCards) { // for debugging purposes
    NSLog(@"Card: %@ index: %d", c.contents, [self.chosenCards indexOfObject:c]);
}

[self.chosenCards removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

I keep getting the following result:

```
2014-11-30 14:58:11.487 Matchismo[12262:60b] Card: 5clubs♦️ index: 0
2014-11-30 14:58:11.487 Matchismo[12262:60b] Card: 6clubs♣️ index: 1
2014-11-30 14:58:23.714 Matchismo[12262:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

Why ): ? Obviously my array contains an object at index 0, and evidently the bounds of the array extend past [0 .. 0].

Comment: Most likely the problem is somewhere else (the index reported in the error is `1` after all). Try to put an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) in order to identify the line that is causing the exception.

Comment: Oy. You win. Put this in an answer and I'll give you that glorious green check mark. It turns out the next line was the problem. The next line is another NSLog test statement; since I wasn't getting the log, I presumed the line I discussed above was the issue, but it turns out there was a typo in my NSLog statement. Which your strategy helped me find. Huzzah. (How embarrassing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the problem is somewhere else (the index reported in the error is `1` after all). Try to put an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) in order to identify the line that is causing the exception ( and possibly save you a lot of time and confusion on any similar issues in the future :) )